# Execute a script when memory peaks?

Tags: scripts, memory, optimization

I don't have a lot of memory and sometimes, when I play video games, its get full and my computer start freezing, anything I do take more than 1 minutes before getting done that include mouse move and mouse click.

So what I want is to be able to kill some process I use and I know I can kill (like my Internet browser) before the memory get full so I have little more space left. Do you know a way to do it ?

In technical terms, what I want is that when the memory is almost full it trigger a script that will send a SIGTERM (order to close) to my Internet browser so my PC don't freeze and I can choose to save whatever I'm doing and reopen my browser or forget about my browser.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, here goes:

```
#!/bin/bash
threshold=100          # Minimum amount of memory left when you should start killing, in MB
browser="firefox-bin"  # Change this to whatever you use, firefox is actually firefox-bin
while true; do
    available=$(free -m | head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}')
    if [ "$threshold" -ge "$available" ]; then
        killall -q $browser  # Will not complain if no processes were killed
    fi
    sleep 20
done
```

Put this into `/home/USERNAME/bin`, execute `chmod +x ~/bin/SCRIPTNAME`, and then add it to your auto-start programs through `System->Preferences->Startup Applications`.

Then the script will run when you log in, automatically. You can run it manually with `~/bin/SCRIPTNAME &`

Comment: You forgot to have an infinite loop to keep the process running and it's `if [ "$threshold" -ge "$available" ];` and not `if [ "$available" -ge "$threshold" ];`. I have corrected this and added a check up to see if the program is running `if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $browser > /dev/null; then ...` and it's working perfectly well. Because the current version of the script doesn't work I'll wait for you to correct it before setting it up as the correct answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Oh my god, I completely screwed that one up :D Thanks, I fixed it - also, is it alright if it uses `killall -q` instead of checking if the process is running? It does not raise any errors for me.

Comment: That should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Killing anything to conserve memory is a bad idea, **especially automatically**. Make sure that you have enough swap and RAM available - of course, running something that uses 1 gig of memory on a 512MB machine is like trying to win a F1 Grand Prix while driving a Corolla.

By which I mean "don't do it."

Comment: I don't understand why it is such a bad idea. My computer it's extremely slow when it's swapping and most of the time I'll just restart the computer because it's faster than to wait for the PC to unfreeze. What I want is to avoid this situation and I don't want to check the memory left all the time to quit applications myself.

Comment: Killing anything automatically can result in unpredictable results. If, say, you were working on a report for your employer and decided to play a game, then BOOM! The report is gone.

If you can tell me a list of processes that you are likely to run and want to kill, post up a list of those unwanted processes. Otherwise, there's no reliable way for your idea to work.

Comment: Refer to my newest answer (below).

Answer (score 1):

[The kernel does that automatically](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer) when you run out of memory.

If you have swap enabled, however, that will take a *lot* of grinding.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting vm.swappiness to 100 as per the instructions here (use 100 instead of 0) On a memory starved machine that can improve performance.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#What%20is%20swappiness%20and%20how%20do%20I%20change%20it?

Comment: Thank you, it seem that it have a good effect on my computer's performances.

Comment: Glad it helps, it seems to do so here as well even on my 3gb machine when I run a big virtual machine or a game. I would look into compcache as well however I am still able to directly verify if it works. :(